# PostgreSQL Increment varchar

Tags: postgresql, increment

Is there a way we can increment a column declared as varchar in PostgreSQL.
IF I have values 0001,0002,0003... in my column how can proceed to add +1?
I tried nextval but it not working.

```
CREATE TABLE tab1 (
matri VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
role VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL,
libelle VARCHAR(40),
util VARCHAR(10),
) 

CREATE TABLE tab2 (
idemploye SERIAL,
nomred VARCHAR(10),
matri VARCHAR(10),
)

Insert into tab1 ("matri", "role", "libelle", "util")
select tab2.matri,tab1.role,'MANAGER',E'MANAGER' from tab1,tab2
where tab2.matri IN (Select matri from tab2);
```

I want my second column "role" to be incremented with every insert.

Comment: The usual approach is to store that as an integer and format that number with leading zeros when _displaying_ it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a_horse_with_no_name has already stated, the ideal here is to store this as an int and format on display, but I assume your system is the way it is for a reason, so.

The way to do this would be, in the select subquery of your insert statement: select the highest existing value, cast to int, increment, cast back to varchar, run through `lpad`, and then just in case no data exists yet, coalesce with '0001'.

```sql
insert into tab1 ("matri", "role", "libelle", "util")
select
    tab2.matri,
    coalesce((select lpad((role::integer + 1)::varchar, 4, '0') from tab1 order by role desc limit 1), '0001'),
    'MANAGER',
    E'MANAGER'
from
    tab2
where
    tab2.matri IN (select matri from tab2);
```

---

An alternative approach would be to create a trigger to do this for you, so you don't need to do this manually everywhere you insert into the table:

```sql
-- Create trigger function
create or replace function tg_fn_tab1_varchar_increment(
) returns trigger as $$
declare
    _r varchar;
begin
    select into _r
        role
    from
        tab1
    order by
        role desc
    limit 1;

    if _r is null then
        NEW.role := '0001';
        return NEW;
    end if;

    NEW.role := lpad((_r::integer + 1)::varchar, 4, '0');

    return NEW;
end;
$$ language plpgsql volatile;

-- Attach trigger
create trigger tg_tab1_varchar_increment before insert on tab1
    for each row execute procedure tg_fn_tab1_varchar_increment();
```

Answer (score 2):

Though the better solution would be to use an integer column and add the padding on display, this works:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE role_seq;
CREATE TABLE roles (role varchar(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT lpad(nextval('role_seq')::varchar, 4, '0'));
INSERT INTO roles VALUES (DEFAULT), (DEFAULT);
SELECT * FROM roles;
--  role
-- ------
--  0001
--  0002
```

Note that you will get gaps in the numbers if you delete rows or an insert transaction rolls back.

Answer (score -1):

Try this...

```
select CONVERT(varchar,substring('0001',1,2)) +
   RIGHT(REPLICATE('0',5) + convert(varchar,(CONVERT(int, substring('0001',3,5)) + 1)) ,5);
```

Comment: I have an error "the column "varchar" doesn't exist"

Comment: what actual values are you putting into the column role ... if it is just numbers you can make it an int instead of varchar and just include an auto-increment

Comment: That is invalid standard SQL and invalid for Postgres

Comment: I convert it to an int then convert it to varchar like this : CAST (CAST(role AS INTEGER)+1 as text). Now is there a way I can prefix it with 000, and 00 if I get to double digits?